# Opening chromium browser with URL from Python file

Tags: raspbian, python

I'm using the google AIY voice project for the Raspberry Pi that came with magpi issue 57. I have had a lot of success despite being new to pi's which is  nice.

I'm struggling to open chromium-browser so that automatically goes to a URL I give it. After searching on the internet I started using selenium and managed to get the browser to open but it wont go to any URL I pass. The current code in my Python file is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

station = 'http://icy-e-bz-04-cr.sharp-stream.com/planetrock.mp3'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser")
driver.get(station)
```

This half works and opens chromium but doesn't then go to the 'station' I provided. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Having looked at some example code most people have the URL directly located in `driver.get ()`. E.g: `driver.get("http://icy-e-bz-04-cr.sharp-stream.com/planetrock.mp3")`. That might be worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

You can also try shell/command line syntax via python

`chromium-browser <web_url> <web_url> <web_url>`

works on raspbian

Answer (score 1):

Follow this code to get your code worked.

```
import webbrowser, os, sys

url = "http://192.168.2.128:5008/"

chrome_path = '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
```

Comment: Is it possible to close the window also form python?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems on a Raspberry B+ with Stretch.
I could solve the issues by

1. creating a symlink named 'google-chrome' pointing to '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser'
2. replacing "driver." in the python-code with "browser." as example below:

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import B
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
usernameStr = 'abcdef'
passwordStr = 'uvwzyx'
findStr1 = 'Welcome abcdef!'
findStr2 = 'Password'

driver = '/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver'
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.binary_location = "/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser"
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

browser.get(('http://192.168.88.1/status'))
delay = 5
for element in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), findStr1)]"):
    et = element.text
    print (et)
    if et == findStr1:
        print ("already connected")
        break
    elif et.find(findStr2):
        print ("not connected yet")
        break
```

In case I would replace 'browser' with 'driver' I would get tons of errors. I was close to give up because elsewhere I found statements, that selenium dos not support raspberry resp chromium-browser anymore.
I am using a script to auto-connect after boot to the wifi network in my apartment.  The lines above are the first commands.
In case of 'connection' (that happens sometimes) the script stops.
In case of 'no connection' the login-form is being filled and submitted by further code, which is not displayed here.
Not 100% your question but you might give this a try.

cheers

Comment: Doesn't work because there is an indention error in the *for* loop.

Comment: This problem might be due to the formatting options in mini-Markdown formatting options of this webpage. (I have to use 4 spaces to display the code)

Comment: Use a code editor like i.E "IDLE" to debug this code or a text-editor and replace blanks in indentation. Indentation needs to be done with tabs instead of blanks. Mixing tabs and spaces causes errors

Comment: I have formated the code. Please check it. For what is `delay = 5`? It isn't used.

Comment: use Python3 IDLE!   
load the code with 'file open' and  click on  'run Check Module'.  
In case of no errors run the code!

Comment: I am running this code in autostart. I give the machine 5 seconds to load the lxde desktop. It is a Raspi B+ with just 512 Mb RAM. That needs some patience!

Comment: Sorry, but I really do not install a graphical environment and IDLE just only for testing this snipped of code. And it can only check syntax, not semantic. I have done my best but it's your code. And what is it with the `delay=5`? It is only defined but no part of the code uses `delay`. I don't understand it. Does any external program we don't see uses this variable? Maybe the autostart?

Comment: looks like a little misunderstanding, I don`t ask for help, since this code is active and working. The intention was to give a hint how  you get your Raspberry working with selenium and chromium-browser.  Cheers again

Comment: You don't ask for help but for me it seems that you needed help in formating ;-)

Comment: We stop here, all is said and done. Reading is the key!